# Sedgewick Quicksort not making total sense

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I understand the concept of quicksort, and most of the implementations I have seen largely make sense to me. However the one by Robert Sedgewick does not, his implementation is along the lines of:

```
        private void sort(int lo, int hi) { 
            if (hi <= lo) return;
            int j = partition(lo, hi);
            sort(lo, j-1);
            sort(j+1, hi);
        }

        private int partition(int lo, int hi) {
            int start = lo;
            int partition = hi + 1;
            int pivot = theArray[lo];
            while (true) { 

                // left to right
                while (less(theArray[++start], pivot))
                    if (start == hi) break;

                // right to left
                while (less(pivot, theArray[--partition]))
                    if (partition == lo) break;  

                // check if pointers cross
                if (start >= partition) break;

                exch(theArray, start, partition);
            }

            // place pivot at partition
            exch(theArray, lo, partition);

            return partition;
        }

        private boolean less(int v, int w) {
            return v < w;
        }

        private void exch(int[] a, int i, int j) {
            int swap = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = swap;
        }
```

I understand all of it except for the partition function. Particularly what happens in the `while(true)` portion

Comment: its doesnt he sorting in there. what's exactly you don't understand there? Did you debug ?

Comment: With little googling, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme

Comment: *"its doesnt he sorting in there."* ?

Comment: @J.J.Hakala it does look similar and it definitely helps explain it, but there is only a single exchange done. It says that _the pivot's final location is not necessarily at the index that was returned_. It looks like in Sedgewick's implementation, the pivot will always be at the value returned (partition index)

Comment: @J.J.Hakala and also user3574076, the while loop is similar to Hoare partition scheme, but after the while loop, the pivot from [lo] is swapped to [partition], similar to Lomuto partition scheme, so the recursive calls are also like Lomuto, sort(lo, pivot-1), sort(pivot+1, hi), unlike Hoare which is sort(lo, pivot), sort(pivot+1, hi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's make some "brain debug"

`int pivot = theArray[lo];`
Fixes 1st element as pivot value

`while (less(theArray[++start], pivot))
                    if (start == hi) break;`
Finds the first element for exchange - the leftmost one bigger than pivot

`while (less(pivot, theArray[--partition]))
                    if (partition == lo) break;`
 Finds the second element for exchange - the rightmost one less than pivot

`if (start >= partition) break;`
Breaks `while (true)` loop when there is no more elements to exchange

`exch(theArray, start, partition);`
Exchanges elements found

Example `[5 3 8 9 2]`:
5 is pivot
first 'bad' element is 8
second one is 2
they are exchanged

`[5 3 2 9 8]`

now first *index* stops at 4 (hi), second index stops at 2, loop breaks, and 5 exchanges with 2.

Result: `[2 3 5 9 8]`
Subranges (2,3,5) and (9,8) are new partitions